# Does selenium have maximum number of clicks of the same button

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, click

I have a selenium web scraping project and there is a button I have  to click it 1600 times but  after 1000 clicks chrome doesn't load the page any more (it just showing the loading sign but does not load the page )
Does selenium have maximum number of clicks ?

If yes, how I could change this maximum number to be larger

Comment: Not sure that there is an limit, maybe your doing it to fast (without delay) - Please, provide some code, that would help to understand, what you are doing exactly.

Comment: Does the click trigger a request/action? It might be wise to wait until that action is finished before clicking again.

Comment: It's not selenium issue it's the webpage issue

Answer (score 0):

[Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) itself doesn't contain any click but contains a method which you can invoke to simulate a **click** on a clickable element.

The [`click()`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/_modules/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.html#WebElement.click) mehtod is defined as:

```
def click(self):
    """Clicks the element."""
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
```

You can invoke the `click()` mehtod on any clickable element as many as possible times you can.

---

Ideally, to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `LINK_TEXT`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Click Link"))).click()
  ```
- Using `PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Click Partial Link"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: I do the wait before but also after 1000 clicks chrome does not load the page any more so is there maximum html content that chrome Webdriver allows ?